# Macro to delete an email

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a macro that forwards an email on to a recipient once a button is clicked. However, I want the macro to also delete the email (sending it to the recycle bin).

Here is the current code. This currently works and forwards the email.

```
Sub forwardEmail()

Dim oExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oOldMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set oExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
If oExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Class = olMail Then
Set oOldMail = oExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Set oMail = oOldMail.forward
oMail.Recipients.Add "Recipients email goes here"
oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolve
If oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolved Then
oMail.Send
Else
MsgBox "Could not resolve " & oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Name
End If
Else
MsgBox "Not a mail item"
End If

End Sub
```

I thought by adding `oMailItem.Delete` to the code would work but it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't clear to me which email you wanted deleted, the original email or the forwarded email from `Sent` items - so these mods provide both options.

```
Sub forwardEmail()
    Dim oExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oOldMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    If oExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Class = olMail Then
        Set oOldMail = oExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Set oMail = oOldMail.Forward
        oMail.Recipients.Add "spam_me"
        oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolve
        If oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolved Then
            'delete forwarded email from sent items
            oMail.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
            oMail.Send
              'delete original email from inbox
            oOldMail.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not resolve " & oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Name
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a mail item"
        End If
End Sub
```