# vba delete email from sent folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to delete an email from the Sent Items folder after the email is forwarded with a rule.

I tried to use "brettdj" code from another post:[Macro to delete an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552620/macro-to-delete-an-email/43399142#43399142) but it's not working for me at all  .

what I'm looking for it's a vba macro that can delete an email when you run the script with the rule.

any idea how I can accomplished that

thanks in advance

Comment: Is all the account under the same Outlook?

Comment: yes all accounts are pulled from the same outlooks session.

Comment: You have invalidated the answer to the question instead of possibly accepting it if it was correct. People will not like this behaviour. Roll back this question and ask a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a corresponding entry in your contacts folder (address book). The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866951.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `Recipients` class accepts the name of the recipient; it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP e-mail address of the recipient.

```
Sub forwardEmail(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
   Dim oExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
   Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim oOldMail As Outlook.MailItem
   Set oExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
   If oExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Class = olMail Then
     Set oOldMail = oExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
     Set oMail = oOldMail.Forward
     oMail.Recipients.Add "test@gmail.com"
     oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolve
     If oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Resolved Then
       'delete forwarded email from sent items
        oMail.DeleteAfterSubmit = True

        oMail.Send
        'delete original email from inbox
        'oOldMail.Delete
     Else
         MsgBox "Could not resolve " & oMail.Recipients.Item(1).Name
     End If
   Else
     MsgBox "Not a mail item"
   End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the update I have like 55 recipients, well it's going to be a challenge, I thought the macro was doing that by default for any forwarded email, well any option without a recipient will be much better then.

Comment: I tried and it's not working, I added an email inside the quote, but it didn't delete the email from the send folder after forwarding the email.